# Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet throws exception when using -Variable parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

When I try to use the Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet from SQL Server 2008 to execute a query that contains scripting variables, ex. `$(MyVar)`, I receive the following exception:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here's the code I'm trying to run (which is copy/paste from [the Books Online example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) with only the connection parameters added).

```
$MyArray = "MyVar1 = 'String1'", "MyVar2 = 'String2'"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT `$(MyVar1) AS Var1, `$(MyVar2) AS Var2;" -Variable $MyArray -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database "master" -UserName "who" -Password "me"
```

If I replace `$(MyVar1)` and `$(MyVar2)` in the `-Query` with `'x'` and `'y'` then it runs perfectly.

```
$MyArray = "MyVar1 = 'String1'", "MyVar2 = 'String2'"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT 'x' AS Var1, 'y' AS Var2;" -Variable $MyArray -ServerInstance "localhost" -Database "master" -UserName "who" -Password "me"
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I posted this same question on the SQL Server forums and, apparently, this is a bug in SQL Server 2008's PowerShell cmdlets... [follow the thread here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/sqltools/thread/0af5b947-2852-41bc-b95d-b19abde18ef7).

Answer (score 5):

Indeed this is a bug in SQL Server - tracked and fixed here
https://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver/feedback/details/358291/invoke-sqlcmd-powershell-cmdlet-fails-when-array-passed-via-variable

However, there's a posted workaround. Remove the spaces around the assignment. So instead of

```
$MyArray = "MyVar1 = 'String1'", "MyVar2 = 'String2'"
```

use

```
$MyArray = "MyVar1='String1'", "MyVar2='String2'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this alone:
PS>$MyArray = "MyVar1 = 'String1'", "MyVar2 = 'String2'"

Now:
PS>$MyArray
and
PS>MyVar1

Now:
PS>$MyArray|get-member

PowerShell thinks you've assigned 2 string objects to $MyArray, nothing more.  This approach does not result in defining the variables $MyVar1 and $MyVar2 to PowerShell.

Sorry, I can't fire up my SQL2008 VM right now to comment on the other parts...

Comment: According to the Books Online example, assigning the 2 strings to the array is exactly what needs to happen since the cmdlet is expecting an array of variable assignments.